# How to output file into google Team (shared) Drive from Colab?

Tags: python

Trying to output some pickle files into google Team (shared) drive from Colab. Note that Team drive is owned by others.

I know how to output files into my google drive from Colab, an issue is frequently asked in the forum. However, I have not seen any related question/answer about how to output to Team drive.

The following code is to output file to drive (mine):

1. creating picke file

```py
import pickle
from google.colab import files
a_file = a_fun(a)

# save pickle in VM temporary
with open('a_file.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(a_file, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

2. banch of packages and relating Colab and Drive

```py
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

3. make the dir of my own drive

```py
!mkdir -p my_Drive 
!google-drive-ocamlfuse my_Drive
```

4. copy the file to drive

```py
!cp /content/a_file.pickle /content/Drive
print('output file success')
```

Is there a way to do a similar trick to the Team drive?

I suspect that there is a problem in the authorization. Since in the case of outputting file to my own drive, it needs the authorization code to access my drive.